# Error installing Microsoft Bot framework emulator

Tags: installation, botframework, squirrel.windows

I'm trying to install "Bot framework emulator V3" on my PC, but I get "The installation has failed" and then I can't do anything. I've already turned off the antivirus and the Windows Firewall... I don't know what to do, and I don't have any information of the error.

Comment: I've removed the windows-installer tag and added the squirrel.windows tag because this installer isn't MSI based it's squirrel based.  It runs in the per user context automatically with no user acceptance even when trying it from the commandline with a /?  argument.  If it was MSI I'd tell you to turn standardized logging on and read the log.  With this squirrel installer I don't know how to do that.

Comment: check C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp

Comment: I will try that... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and attempted multiple times to install via the link.

Now I was able to run the emulator by downloading and installing it myself following these instructions:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/wiki/How-to-Contribute#clone-and-build

None of the other solutions (i.e. running .net fix, etc) worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm going to try that. Now I've installed an old version and I'm debuggin from the web, but it's a pain in the neck

Comment: Let me know how it goes.  It was pretty straight forward following the steps and works.